# BATCH : SET variable in IF statement into LOOP with setlocal enableDelayedExpansion enabled : IMPOSSIBLE

Tags: loops, batch-file, if-statement, set

I have a pb with this batch script, i already spend 1 hour to try to get it fix ! but no chance

I try to set the variable TYP with string regarding condition (CON is a string), the pb concern the TYP variable. I can't set this variable and of course i can't echo the value.

I need help

```
@ECHO OFF
 cls

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

SET ROOT="C:\Users\7642FH\Local\RawFile"
SET ROOT=%ROOT:~1%
SET ROOT=%ROOT:~0,-1%
SET TYPE1=Actual
SET TYPE1=Forcast
set TYP =

FOR /F  %%d in ('DIR %ROOT% /AD /B') DO (

  FOR /F  %%f in ('DIR "%ROOT%\%%d\*.*" /B') DO (
      echo %%d
      ECHO %%f
      SET x=%%f
      set y=!x:~0,3%!


   IF CON ==!y! (
        set TYP = aaa
        echo aaa
        echo !TYP!
        ) else (
        echo rrr
        set TYP = rrrr
        echo !TYP!
        )

  )
)

endlocal
echo on
```

Comment: We need more info. What are you expecting to happen when you run the script? What is actually happening when you run the script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set y=!x:~0,3%!
```

has an extra % sign in it.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is here:

```
set TYP = aaa
```

and here:

```
set TYP = rrrr
```

You define a variable named "TYP ", not "TYP"

write

```
set TYP=aaa
```

instead. (or reference it with `!TYP !` if the space is an intended part of the variable name)

or even better:

```
set "TYP=aaa"
```

which prevents unintended spaces at the end of the value.